# Defining general recurrence expression and extracting coefficient

Tags: numerics, difference-equations, coefficients, finite-difference-method

I'm new to Mathematica and I wish to solve a difference equation which is defined by the relation:
$y_{i-1}-2y_{i} +y_{i+1} = f(x_i,y_i),\\y_0 = a, y_n = b.$.

Where $x_i$ is given for all $i$.

I want to be able to-

1. Define this expression in general terms as written above so that I can use this expression for any i from 1 to n-1.
2. Rearrange the terms of this expression so that I can then extract the coefficient of $y_{i},y_{i-1},y_{i+1}$ and enter them in a Matrix to further solve the equation.

How do I achieve the above on Mathematica? I do not wish to use RSolve or Solve, those are not the solutions I am looking for (I want to implement a custom method to solve this).

Comment: Welcome to MMA SE! I'm a bit confused by the presence of $x_i$ in $f(x_i,y_i)$. Are you given $x_i$ for all $i$?

Comment: Yes, I'll add that specification to the question, my bad. $x_i$ is known for all i.

Comment: `yn == b` does not make much sense, do you mean y0==b? And what should `f`be?

Comment: It is a boundary value problem with the boundary values given as $y_0 = a, y_n = b$. $f$ can be any linear function such as $x+y$ etc.

Comment: Might be good to give a small explicit example and show desired output(s).